# 2 installer processes in Task manager

Tags: install4j

I observed that there are 2 processes(instances) of the installer i created. I also observed that this happens when we run the installer as a normal user (even after the UAC prompt). But when we execute through "Run as Admin" it has only 1 instance. Is this expected? How do we justify it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second process is the helper process with elevated privileges that is started by the "Require privileges" action. It executes actions whose "Action elevation type" property resolves to "Elevate to maximum available privileges".